# Aws ec2 directory does html take priority over php if I upload both?

Tags: php, html, amazon-web-services, active-directory

My question is a directory question. If I install a php script in a directory and I install an index.html file. Will the html file take priority when the domain is visited?
What I'm trying to do if work on a php script live by typing in [www.domainname.com/index.php](http://www.domainname.com/index.php) but when visitors type in the [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) I want it to take them to the html index.html. is this possible?

Another question, I installed a domain name and installed a placeholder index.html in the directory, I then created a subdirectory like [www.domainname.com/restaurants/](http://www.domainname.com/restaurants/). This directory has an index.html file in it but it's not showing up in the browser. I created the directory in file zilla. Could there be a way I can find out why this is?

Answer (score 0):

you may update nginx settings in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

something like this:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain www.your_domain;
    root /var/www/your_domain;

    index index.html index.htm index.php; // "add index.php here 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```